# How would you say "How complicated!"

Tags: anglais, exclamations

I am playing a correspondence chess game, and I would like to say to my opponent, "How complicated!" in reference to the position. How would I go about saying this in French?

I plugged it into Google Translate and it gives me **Quelle complication!** This uses  a noun, not an adjective, and I was wondering whether there is a closer French equivalent.

Comment: @Alone-zee I actually figured that out *after* I suggested the edit and then couldn't find a way to undo my suggestion. Feel free to discard my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use the following:

> Qu'est-ce que c'est compliqué !
>
> Ce que c'est compliqué !
>
> Mais c'est que c'est compliqué !
>
> Que c’est compliqué !
>
> Que de complexité !
>
> Quelle complexité !
>
> Comme c’est compliqué(, ça) !
>
> <s>Combien compliqué !</s>
>
> <s>(Mais) ô combien compliqué !</s>

Comment: In French they'd never say *combien compliqué*. *Quelle complexité* exists but  I would not use it here.

Comment: @Laure Hi. Wouldn't you use "Combien compliqué !" as a short cut to saying "Combien c'est compliqué !"? I heard this "combien" construction used in Switzerland. :)

Comment: In France *Que c'est compliqué* (not *combien*) is the most common way to express it.

Comment: C'est ben compliqué ton _move_  (ou _ton affaire_) là ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I would tend to say “Comme c'est compliqué !” or “Ce que c'est compliqué !”. The second sentence can be shortened to “Que c'est compliqué !”, or lengthened to “Que'est-ce que c'est compliqué”, without any change in meaning or usage (except that because “qu'est-ce que c'est …” is longer, it's also slightly more emphatic).

In this particular case, “Comme c'est …” and “Ce que c'est …” are interchangeable, but this is not always the case. I'm having a hard time identifying the difference, but there are cases where I would tend to use rather than the other, and others where both are equally possible.

> Regarde la toile que j'ai peinte. — Comme elle est jolie !
>   Voici ma maison. — Comme / Ce qu'elle est grande !
>   J'attends depuis des heures. Comme c'est long !
>   (Ce) qu'il fait chaud aujourd'hui !
>   Comme c'est étrange !
>   Comme c'est gentil !

I feel that “comme c'est X” emphasizes that the binary quality X (it's X or not X) is remarkable, whereas “que c'est X” emphasizes that X is true to a high degree. In many cases there is no material distinction between the two, but sometimes one works better than the other. But I'm not sure if this explains all the examples.

“Ce que c'est …” can get further emphasis by expanding it to “Ce que ça peut être …”.

> Ce que ça peut être compliqué !
>   Ce que cette position peut être compliquée !

But:

> Comme cette position est compliquée !

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple one with an overtone of irony:

> C'est bien compliqué!

Or more colloquial:

> C'est super compliqué!
>
> C'est dingue ce que ça peut être compliqué!

Answer (score 1):

There's a good general answer already, but to complement it with more colloquial (and ungrammatical) language:

> Comment c'est compliqué !
>
> Trop compliqué ! (Trop *literally means "too much" but can be used to mean "very"*)
>
> Abusé comme c'est compliqué !

Answer (score -3):

One that Alone-Zee didn't mention too you is:

comment compliqué

Comment: No, French speakers would never say that.